# How I will get text (GET TEXT) in html which has text and other field in the same tags in Robot Framework?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

```
    ${cont_num}=    GET TEXT    //*[@id="root"]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/h6/text()
    Log    ${cont_num}
```

**Below is the HTML**
[image]

**Below is the inspected xpath**
[image]

**Finally below is the Error**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `text()` from your locator - it's an xpath function, returning the text as a string; it's of no use for selenium (in fact, it leads to the error - the returned value is not a DOM element).

```
//*[@id="root"]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/h6
```